# Integration by parts (Simple Question)

Tags: integration

First I'd like to say sorry for not giving the context in the title, I think it would be very long and a bit abstract.

$\ \int xln(x) \,dx= \frac{ x^2}{2}ln(x) - \int  \frac{x^2}{2}\frac{1}{x}dx\
\\\int xln(x) \,dx = \frac{ x^2}{2}ln(x) - \frac{x^2}{4}\
 $

Why after $ \frac{x^2}{4}$ I don't sum a constant ?

Comment: You do if you aren't given bounds.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You should be adding a constant.

Comment: Indeed. You *should* have an arbitrary constant of integration.  It looks like your source was being a bit lazy and not explicitly including it with these indefinite integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an indefinite integral, there should *always* be a constant of integration. People do often leave it off because they're lazy, but if you don't include it, you can produce silly paradoxical results.